# order how spring scan the beans defined with @service @component or @repository

Tags: java, spring

anyone of you do know which rule use when scan to instanced the spring beans defined with @component, @service or @repository, since when deploy an application into a environment spring instanced beans in one order and on other environment(with the same characteristics as the previous) the order is totally different, and because of this I get an error related to cyclic dependencies.

thanks,
sorin

Comment: If you're getting an error because of cyclic dependencies, no reordering can possibly help you, by definition. There's some other problem.

Comment: yes ... but the same problem I had(the cyclic dependency) also on the first env, and there it's working, on the second since the order of instated is different(i don't know why or what influence this) and I get into cyclic dependency problem

Comment: or do you know a method to find that cyclic dependency? instead of look into spring boot logs, since there is a lot of spring beans that are very tied link between them.